# Check whether the SD card is available or not programmatically

Tags: android, sd-card

My app is working for mobiles which have an SD card only. So programmatically I want to check if the SD card is available or not and how to find the SD card free space. Is it possible?

If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: What does "SD card only" mean? Do you mean it has no internal memory? That's hard to imagine.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
Boolean isSDSupportedDevice = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();

if(isSDSupportedDevice && isSDPresent)
{
  // yes SD-card is present
}
else
{
 // Sorry
}
```

Comment: how to check the sdcard free memory?

Comment: but it return true if phone has inbuild storage..so not the correct answer

Comment: On modern Android devices, external storage (known as "sdcard") can now be also internal storage, just separate. So yes, it is a good answer.

Comment: Also it's a good idea to check not only Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED, but also Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY

Comment: To determine if external storage is a SDCARD use the above in conjunction with: Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()

Comment: "External storage" is not necessarily an SD card. On many devices - most devices that I have seen recently - there is emulated "external" storage that is not an SD card (at least not a removable one). So this will give you a wrong answer. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() "Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. ... it may also be implemented as built-in storage ..."

Comment: This returns true for a device that has no SD card and only internal memory.

Comment: check this if phone has inbuild storage http://stackoverflow.com/a/40282882/3758898

Comment: This is clearly a wrong answer in case of emulated external storage. Ideally Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() should be used.
You can also see Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated().

@naresh you should not accept a partial answer.

Comment: even though emulator has a SD card available on it in android studio, this test condition didn't return true.

Comment: on samsung glaxy a52, after inserting sd card isSDPresent  return true, but isSDSupportedDevice  return false.

Answer (score 24):

Accepted answer doesn't work for me

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

In case if device has a built-in storage, it returns true;
**My solution** is that to check the external files directory count, if there is more than one, device has sdcard. 
It works and I tested it for several devices.

```
public static boolean hasRealRemovableSdCard(Context context) {
    return ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null).length >= 2;
}
```

Comment: But if there is a slot in device and sd card is not inserted, it shows length as 2. The file array has null file. Anyway it is a best solution for me :)

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili I tested it on Samsung J2 (API 22) `5.1` and works fine. Thank you so much

Comment: ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs has ANR on some devices

Answer (score 16):

You can check if external removable sd card is available like this

```
public static boolean externalMemoryAvailable(Activity context) {
    File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

This works perfectly as i have tested it.

Comment: I have tested it on Samsung A70s, with and without an external(removable) SD card, and in both cases, it's working fine. I have tried all the suggested solutions by others but this one worked correctly. Hopefully will work also for all devices. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` as described in ["Using the External Storage"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

To get available space on external storage, use [`StatFs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html):

```
// do this only *after* you have checked external storage state:
File extdir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File stats = new StatFs(extdir.getAbsolutePath());
int availableBytes = stats.getAvailableBlocks() * stats.getBlockSize();
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a little class for that checking the storage state. Maybe it's of some use for you.

```
import android.os.Environment;

/**
 * Checks the state of the external storage of the device.
 * 
 * @author kaolick
 */
public class StorageHelper
{
// Storage states
private boolean externalStorageAvailable, externalStorageWriteable;

/**
 * Checks the external storage's state and saves it in member attributes.
 */
private void checkStorage()
{
// Get the external storage's state
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
    // Storage is available and writeable
    externalStorageAvailable = externalStorageWriteable = true;
}
else if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))
{
    // Storage is only readable
    externalStorageAvailable = true;
    externalStorageWriteable = false;
}
else
{
    // Storage is neither readable nor writeable
    externalStorageAvailable = externalStorageWriteable = false;
}
}

/**
 * Checks the state of the external storage.
 * 
 * @return True if the external storage is available, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isExternalStorageAvailable()
{
checkStorage();

return externalStorageAvailable;
}

/**
 * Checks the state of the external storage.
 * 
 * @return True if the external storage is writeable, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isExternalStorageWriteable()
{
checkStorage();

return externalStorageWriteable;
}

/**
 * Checks the state of the external storage.
 * 
 * @return True if the external storage is available and writeable, false
 *         otherwise.
 */    
public boolean isExternalStorageAvailableAndWriteable()
{
checkStorage();

if (!externalStorageAvailable)
{
    return false;
}
else if (!externalStorageWriteable)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
}
```

Comment: does this calss helps detect sd card availability ?

Comment: @PankajNimgade This class helps you to check if external storage is available and/or writable. External storage can be an SD-card or built-in storage like in the nexus devices.

Comment: is it possible to check specifically for the "sdcard" ?, Thanks in advance

Comment: @PankajNimgade Not that I know of. I would recommend to read about Internal and External storage here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: been through that and several other documents, there is no specific difference made by google on "external storage available on device" and "sd card"....... :(

Answer (score 4):

I modified it such that if an SD card exists, it sets the path there. If not, it sets it at the internal directory.

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
if(isSDPresent)
{
    path = theAct.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/GrammarFolder";
}
else
{
    path = theAct.getFilesDir() + "/GrammarFolder";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 void updateExternalStorageState() {
     String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
     if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
     } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
       mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
     } else {
       mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
handleExternalStorageState(mExternalStorageAvailable,
        mExternalStorageWriteable);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple method is worked for me. Tested in all type of devices.

```
public boolean externalMemoryAvailable() {
    if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
      //device support sd card. We need to check sd card availability.
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      return state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) || state.equals(
          Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY);
    } else {
      //device not support sd card. 
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin

```
fun Context.externalMemoryAvailable(): Boolean {
    val storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)
    return storages.size > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static boolean hasSdCard(Context context) {

    File[] dirs = context.getExternalFilesDirs("");        
    if(dirs.length >= 2 && dirs[1]!=null){
        if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(dirs[1])){ // Extra Check
            return true;
        }
     }
    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a class to check if the folder on the SD card is available or not:

```
public class GetFolderPath {

    static String folderPath;

    public static String getFolderPath(Context context) {
        if (isSdPresent() == true) {
            try {
                File sdPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/FolderName");
                if(!sdPath.exists()) {
                    sdPath.mkdirs();
                    folderPath = sdPath.getAbsolutePath();
                } else if (sdPath.exists()) {
                    folderPath = sdPath.getAbsolutePath();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
            folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/FolderName/";
        }
        else {
            try {
                File cacheDir=new File(context.getCacheDir(),"FolderName/");
                if(!cacheDir.exists()) {
                    cacheDir.mkdirs();
                    folderPath = cacheDir.getAbsolutePath();
                } else if (cacheDir.exists()) {
                    folderPath = cacheDir.getAbsolutePath();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        return folderPath;
    }

    public static boolean isSdPresent() {
        return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
** i fixed this with help of @Jemo Mgebrishvili answer**
```

this works perfectly even if sd card is present and in the ejected state

```
 if (ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null).length >= 2) {
                File[] f = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null);
                for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
                    File file = f[i];
                    if(file!=null && i ==1)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG,file.getAbsolutePath()+ "external sd card  available");

                    }

                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, " external sd card not available");

            }
```