# Detecting if SD card present or not always returns true

Tags: java, android, sd-card

I am developing an android app, where i am trying to check if SD card is present or not to perform a specfic task.I am using the code from the below link to check it.

[Check whether the SD card is available or not programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429228/check-whether-the-sd-card-is-available-or-not-programatically)

The problem is , the code is working fine for many of my phones, but on my Galaxy S , even if i dont have a SD card, the isSDcardpresent is always a true.

Not sure what the problem is, Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429228/check-whether-the-sd-card-is-available-or-not-programmatically/45731929#45731929

Answer (score 4):

There is always an 'external' storage directory, even for device without SD card, 
see [getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) :

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

It may also **not** be the real SD card, see [Data storage guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) :

> It's possible that a device using a partition of the internal storage
>   for the external storage may also offer an SD card slot. In this case,
>   the SD card is not part of the external storage and your app cannot
>   access it (the extra storage is intended only for user-provided media
>   that the system scans).

I think the question 'is the SD card present ?' should be translated to 'is the shared directory available ?'.