Delphi 12 Android access to SharedRingtonesPath denied
Testing on Android version 13, using Delphi 12.
I have a range of mp3 files, which I always copied into the SharedRingtonesPath from the App internal directory.
These are used by the NotificationChannels, and in some cases played directly.
Now suddenly the copying of the files into the SharedRingtonesPath fails, without any errors.
After copying, the destination directory is simply empty.
This completely stuffs up the working of my App which requires these sound files to be played in certain conditions. Both as warnings via the NotificationChannels and direct.
How can I fix this?  It worked before (on the same phone) when using an earlier version of Delphi.

Why are you using the ringtones folder for notification sounds? Android actually has a dedicated folder for notification sounds. TPath doesn't have a method for it, but you can use the Android API directly to get it.

I founbd this (from you): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715697/check-whether-the-sd-card-is-available-or-not-programmatically-using-delphi  But the "TJEnvironment.JavaClass.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS" returns a Jstring not a JFile, and I cannot get the "getAbsolutePath" to work. It only returns "Notifications/" . How do I get the full path?

Use a different folder such as SharedDocumentsPath for your app's files.

@BartKindt by passing it as an argument to either Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() or Context.getExternalFilesDir()

Than worked. Thanks Remy.
