# creating folder not visible in file explorer

Tags: android

Hi i am creating folder in external storage.first i need to check that Sd card is present or not.In my mobile i dont have sd card.i am using redmi mobile.Below is my code.I dnt have sd card bt i am getting sd card is mounted.Then i checked my internal storage i cant found the folder what i created.i had tried so many codes,please help me.i also added read and write external permission.
my code is:`

```
String state;
        state=Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Sd card found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File root=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            File dir=new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/myappfile");

            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdir();
            }


        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SD card not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`
```

Comment: Which is the version of Android where you are trying it? If it is upper v6 (API 23) you need to request runtime permission to write in the external storage

Comment: `dir.mkdir();`. You are not checking the return value. You should check it as it might fail to create the directory. If it fails display a toast to the user telling so. And return. Do not continue with the code.

Comment: `i am creating folder in external storage.first i need to check that Sd card is present or not`. No not at all as external storage directory has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card. External storage is always present.

Comment: @ alberto..thank you .i forgot to write run time permissions for mmarshmallow...now folder is created..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // yes SD-card is present
 }
else
{
 // Sorry
 }
```

Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7429264/1649353

And also check Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()

Comment: `// yes SD-card is present`. Nonsense. External storage will be present. Has nothing to do with a micro SD card.

Comment: that is why I wrote to check for Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()

Comment: @tthank you all..i forgot to add runtime permissions for marshmallow..now its working

Answer (score 0):

Try someting like this

```
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environnement.getExternalStorageState()))
{
   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myappfile");
   if (!f.exists()) {
      if.mkdirs();
   }
}
```