# Check if external SD card exists in device

Tags: android, android-external-storage

How to check is external MicroSD card exists?

`Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` and `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()` don't help because of mounted inner memory, especially in devices with no slot for SD card.

Is there any working solution?

Comment: what do you mean by mounted inner memory?

Comment: Try this answer, or other in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42623067/5980046

Comment: Jack the Ripper thanx, that really helped